# Estimating the Hubble constant of Virgo Cluster questions?

Tags: astronomy

Im estimating the $H_0$ ([Hubble constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubble_constant)) using the calculated distance to galaxy (M100) in the Virgo cluster, but given that the cluster is about 1-2 megaparcecs in diameter, what issues can I expect to face with using this method?

Also, I've used the mean recession velocity of the Virgo cluster to estimate the $H_0$. Is it more accurate to use the recession velocity of M100 instead? If so why?